# Is plastic package for oscillator bad for EMC?

Tags: clock, emc, crystal

I usually use oscillators with metal/ceramic package, but I am inherited with a design that uses plastic package.  Now it failed radiated emission that aligns with its harmonics.  I understand many things can cause this issue.  But just wonder in general, is plastic package for oscillator bad for EMC?  Here's the component: https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/microchip-technology/DSC1001DI5-024-5760/6098181

Comment: It's 2mm across, how much radiation do you think could come from the component itself? What about wires, traces, or PCB regions that are driven with signals synchronized to it instead?

Comment: jsmith, Have you tried to replace the plastic package with one that uses a metal package, yet, to see if things change at all? Assuming you can find or otherwise adapt to test this. Is there a way you can quickly test your hypothesis, in short?

Comment: These problems almost always originate from long traces attached to the part, rather than the part itself. In some cases you can also attach passives close to the oscillator to act as "slope control" and reduce EMI. Please post schematics + layout.